# unable to create view because of different number of columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create View [lossrun].vw_StagingDailyClaim as 
SELECT 
TPA,
ClaimNumber,
ClientName,
ClaimStatus,
DateReported,
DateOfLoss,
EntryDate,
DateClosed,
DateReopened,
AccidentDescription,
EffectiveDate,
ExpirationDate,
PolicyNumber,
AccidentState,
RiskState,
JurisdictionState,
Carrier,
LOBDescription,
ProgramCode,
PEO,
LossPaid,
MedicalPaid,
SubroRecovery,
SalvageRecovery,
DeductRecovery,
ExpensePaid,
Recovery,
LossOS,
MedicalOS,
ExpenseOS,
Incurred,
InsuredName,
DateCreated,
CreatedBy,
UpdatedBy,
DateUpdated,
CatastropheNumb,
IndemnityRecovery,
ExpenseRecovery,
CurrentAdjuster
FROM
(
SELECT       'Athens' as  TPA , ClaimNumber, ClaimStatus, DateReported, DateOfLoss, EntryDate, DateClosed, DateReopened, AccidentDescription, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, PolicyNumber, AccidentState, RiskState, JurisdictionState, Carrier, 
                         LOBDescription, ProgramCode, PEO, LossPaid, ExpensePaid, Recovery, LossOS, ExpenseOS, Incurred, InsuredName, DateCreated, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, DateUpdated
FROM            Lossrun.LandingAthensDailyClaim
UNION 
SELECT        'CBSC' as  TPA
,ClaimNumber
, ClaimStatus
, DateReported
, DateOfLoss
, EntryDate
, DateClosed
, DateReopened
, AccidentDescription
, EffectiveDate
, ExpirationDate
, PolicyNumber
, AccidentState
, RiskState
, JurisdictionState
, Carrier
, LOBDescription, ProgramCode, PEO, LossPaid, ExpensePaid, Recovery, LossOS, ExpenseOS, Incurred, InsuredName, DateCreated, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, DateUpdated
FROM            Lossrun.LandingCBSCDailyClaim
UNION ALL
SELECT   
'NARS' as TPA
,ClaimNumber
,ClientName
,ClaimStatus
,cast(DateReported as Date) DateReported
,cast(DateOfLoss as Date) DateOfLoss
,EntryDate
,cast(DateClosed as Date) DateClosed
,cast(DateReopened as Date) DateReopened
,AccidentDescription
,EffectiveDate
,ExpirationDate
,PolicyNumber
,AccidentState
,RiskState
,JurisdictionState
,Carrier
,LOBDescription
,ProgramCode
,PEO
,LossPaid
,MedicalPaid
,SubroRecovery
,SalvageRecovery
,DeductRecovery
,ExpensePaid
,Recovery
,LossOS
,MedicalOS
,ExpenseOS
,Incurred
,InsuredName
,DateCreated
,CreatedBy
,UpdatedBy
,DateUpdated
,CatastropheNumb
 from Lossrun.LandingNARSDailyClaim
 UNION
SELECT
'RMA' as TPA
,ClaimNumber
,ClientName
,ClaimStatus
,cast(DateReported as Date) DateReported
,cast(DateOfLoss as Date) DateOfLoss
,EntryDate
,cast(DateClosed as Date) DateClosed
,cast(DateReopened as Date) DateReopened
,AccidentDescription
,EffectiveDate
,ExpirationDate
,PolicyNumber
,AccidentState
,RiskState
,JurisdictionState
,Carrier
,LOBDescription
,ProgramCode
,PEO
,LossPaid
,MedicalPaid
,SubroRecovery
,SalvageRecovery
,DeductRecovery
,ExpensePaid
,Recovery
,LossOS
,MedicalOS
,ExpenseOS
,Incurred
,InsuredName
,DateCreated
,CreatedBy
,UpdatedBy
,DateUpdated
,CatastropheNumb
 from Lossrun.LandingNARSDailyClaim
 )Q
```

This is error statement in SSMS
"All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."
 why can't i create view like this?

Comment: You should only use `union` if the number of columns and their types are identical cross all result sets. Your error would suggest they are not.

Comment: Did you mean for the `'NARS'` and `'RMA'` subqueries to both pull from `Lossrun.LandingNARSDailyClaim`?

Comment: Do you have any authority to change the core database schema? One table per country/region is unmanageable, not normalized, and leads to difficult queries such as this. Better is one table with a column for country/region.

Comment: Your replies helped me thanks but the view is created but when i try to select data from view ssms is giving me this error .
"Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sub queries need to have the same number of columns, with the same names and datatypes, and in the same order. If some subqueries/tables don't have columns that other subqueries/tables do, you still need to define those columns.

For example, `Lossrun.LandingAthensDailyClaim` doesn't have a `ClientName` column defined in its subquery. But based on the view definition and other subqueries, we still need to add it. We can use `NULL` for the value in this case.

Taking your view definition, I came up with the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW lossrun.vw_StagingDailyClaim
AS
SELECT
    TPA
    ,ClaimNumber
    ,ClientName
    ,ClaimStatus
    ,DateReported
    ,DateOfLoss
    ,EntryDate
    ,DateClosed
    ,DateReopened
    ,AccidentDescription
    ,EffectiveDate
    ,ExpirationDate
    ,PolicyNumber
    ,AccidentState
    ,RiskState
    ,JurisdictionState
    ,Carrier
    ,LOBDescription
    ,ProgramCode
    ,PEO
    ,LossPaid
    ,MedicalPaid
    ,SubroRecovery
    ,SalvageRecovery
    ,DeductRecovery
    ,ExpensePaid
    ,Recovery
    ,LossOS
    ,MedicalOS
    ,ExpenseOS
    ,Incurred
    ,InsuredName
    ,DateCreated
    ,CreatedBy
    ,UpdatedBy
    ,DateUpdated
    ,CatastropheNumb
    ,IndemnityRecovery
    ,ExpenseRecovery
    ,CurrentAdjuster
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TPA = 'Athens'
        ,ClaimNumber
        ,ClientName = NULL
        ,ClaimStatus
        ,DateReported
        ,DateOfLoss
        ,EntryDate
        ,DateClosed
        ,DateReopened
        ,AccidentDescription
        ,EffectiveDate
        ,ExpirationDate
        ,PolicyNumber
        ,AccidentState
        ,RiskState
        ,JurisdictionState
        ,Carrier
        ,LOBDescription
        ,ProgramCode
        ,PEO
        ,LossPaid
        ,MedicalPaid = NULL
        ,SubroRecovery = NULL
        ,SalvageRecovery = NULL
        ,DeductRecovery = NULL
        ,ExpensePaid
        ,Recovery
        ,LossOS
        ,MedicalOS = NULL
        ,ExpenseOS
        ,Incurred
        ,InsuredName
        ,DateCreated
        ,CreatedBy
        ,UpdatedBy
        ,DateUpdated
        ,CatastropheNumb = NULL
        ,IndemnityRecovery = NULL
        ,ExpenseRecovery = NULL
        ,CurrentAdjuster = NULL
    FROM Lossrun.LandingAthensDailyClaim
    UNION
    SELECT
        TPA = 'CBSC'
        ,ClaimNumber
        ,ClientName = NULL
        ,ClaimStatus
        ,DateReported
        ,DateOfLoss
        ,EntryDate
        ,DateClosed
        ,DateReopened
        ,AccidentDescription
        ,EffectiveDate
        ,ExpirationDate
        ,PolicyNumber
        ,AccidentState
        ,RiskState
        ,JurisdictionState
        ,Carrier
        ,LOBDescription
        ,ProgramCode
        ,PEO
        ,LossPaid
        ,MedicalPaid = NULL
        ,SubroRecovery = NULL
        ,SalvageRecovery = NULL
        ,DeductRecovery = NULL
        ,ExpensePaid
        ,Recovery
        ,LossOS
        ,MedicalOS = NULL
        ,ExpenseOS
        ,Incurred
        ,InsuredName
        ,DateCreated
        ,CreatedBy
        ,UpdatedBy
        ,DateUpdated
        ,CatastropheNumb = NULL
        ,IndemnityRecovery = NULL
        ,ExpenseRecovery = NULL
        ,CurrentAdjuster = NULL
    FROM Lossrun.LandingCBSCDailyClaim
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        TPA = 'NARS'
        ,ClaimNumber
        ,ClientName
        ,ClaimStatus
        ,DateReported = CAST(DateReported AS DATE)
        ,DateOfLoss = CAST(DateOfLoss AS DATE)
        ,EntryDate
        ,DateClosed = CAST(DateClosed AS DATE)
        ,DateReopened = CAST(DateReopened AS DATE)
        ,AccidentDescription
        ,EffectiveDate
        ,ExpirationDate
        ,PolicyNumber
        ,AccidentState
        ,RiskState
        ,JurisdictionState
        ,Carrier
        ,LOBDescription
        ,ProgramCode
        ,PEO
        ,LossPaid
        ,MedicalPaid
        ,SubroRecovery
        ,SalvageRecovery
        ,DeductRecovery
        ,ExpensePaid
        ,Recovery
        ,LossOS
        ,MedicalOS
        ,ExpenseOS
        ,Incurred
        ,InsuredName
        ,DateCreated
        ,CreatedBy
        ,UpdatedBy
        ,DateUpdated
        ,CatastropheNumb
        ,IndemnityRecovery = NULL
        ,ExpenseRecovery = NULL
        ,CurrentAdjuster = NULL
    FROM Lossrun.LandingNARSDailyClaim
    UNION
    SELECT
        TPA = 'RMA'
        ,ClaimNumber
        ,ClientName
        ,ClaimStatus
        ,DateReported = CAST(DateReported AS DATE)
        ,DateOfLoss = CAST(DateOfLoss AS DATE)
        ,EntryDate
        ,DateClosed = CAST(DateClosed AS DATE)
        ,DateReopened = CAST(DateReopened AS DATE)
        ,AccidentDescription
        ,EffectiveDate
        ,ExpirationDate
        ,PolicyNumber
        ,AccidentState
        ,RiskState
        ,JurisdictionState
        ,Carrier
        ,LOBDescription
        ,ProgramCode
        ,PEO
        ,LossPaid
        ,MedicalPaid
        ,SubroRecovery
        ,SalvageRecovery
        ,DeductRecovery
        ,ExpensePaid
        ,Recovery
        ,LossOS
        ,MedicalOS
        ,ExpenseOS
        ,Incurred
        ,InsuredName
        ,DateCreated
        ,CreatedBy
        ,UpdatedBy
        ,DateUpdated
        ,CatastropheNumb
        ,IndemnityRecovery = NULL
        ,ExpenseRecovery = NULL
        ,CurrentAdjuster = NULL
    FROM Lossrun.LandingNARSDailyClaim
) Q;
```

Comment: Your replies helped me thanks but the view is created but when i try to select data from view ssms is giving me this error .
"Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @ETL-BI That's why I said all columns in the sub queries need the same names and datatypes. I'd say try removing those `CAST()s` first.

Answer (score 2):

Union statements require an equal number of columns and each column needs to match type. Without the table definitions it's hard for us to narrow down, but you have a different amount of columns in your separate select statements as well.

Try adding one section at a time to the union as a select statement and pay attention to the column types, and once you can run the select statement by itself, then create the view definition.

Comment: Your replies helped me thanks but the view is created but when i try to select data from view ssms is giving me this error .
"Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: This means you have data that can't use to_date(). And then you'll need to either fix the source data or change your where clause to ensure you don't select it.